# Fileupload Data Loses when checkbox is checked?

Tags: c#, asp.net

any help Please.How can I fix problem like when ever I check check box at that time file path is losing from file upload. How can I retain the vlue of my fileupload ? I am using asp.net c#

Comment: Never heard of such a thing. You have a webform with a checkbox and fileupload *server* controls? Is there JS running when the check state changes? If so, what does it do?

Comment: make sure the checkbox does **NOT**, I repeat, NOT do a postback.

Comment: Check if the checkbox is in Autopostback